# Is it appropriate to run correlation on continuous y value with discrete x value?

Tags: r, regression, data, correlation

I am dealing with temperature data that are measured in different distances away from the forest edge (0m, 10m,30m,50m,80m) and I would like to find out whether the temperature will drop as the distance away from the edge increases. I tried to use geom_point to plot the temperature with respect to the distance, however, the x axis value are not labelled as 0m, 10m,30m,50m and 80m, may I ask how to change it?

Also I would like to ask is it appropriate to run correlation using temperature and distance from the edge to show that they are negatively correlated in this situation? I saw correlation should be based on two continuous variable, but the distances from the edge are discrete variable, so should I just present the result using boxplot? Or is computing regression appropriate in this case?[image]

[image: enter image ddddasdfasf here]

Answer (score 3):

Your feature "Distance from the edge" is represented as a factor (), which means it is interpreted as a categorical variable. You need to make sure that it is interpreted as a numerical (either integer or double) and this should label it appropriately in your plot and also correctly display the distance between them (as they are not evenly spaced).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) might help to get the type right.

Check [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/172577/110091) for a discussion on what correlation methods to use for continuous and discrete variables.